# Convert locals to string with literal curly braces

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to convert a locals variable to string.

```
locals {
  env_vars = {
    STAGE = "${var.environment}"
    ENVIRONMENT = "${var.environment}"
    REGION = "${var.region}"
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION = "${var.region}"
  }
}

container_definitions = templatefile("${path.module}/task-definitions/ecs-web-app.json", {
    # This works just fine:
    #ENVIRONMENT_VARS    = <<EOT
    #                        {"name":"STAGE","value":"${var.environment}"},
    #                        {"name":"ENVIRONMENT","value":"${var.environment}"},
    #                        {"name":"REGION","value":"${var.region}"},
    #                        {"name":"AWS_DEFAULT_REGION","value":"${var.region}"}
    #                      EOT


    # But I'm trying to get this to work instead:
    ENVIRONMENT_VARS    = join(",", [for key, value in local.env_vars : "{{\"name\":\"${key}\",\"value\":\"${value}}}\""])
    }
```

Where foo.json is:

```
[
    {
        "environment":[
            ${ENVIRONMENT_VARS}
        ]
    }
]
```

The error I get is:

`Error: ECS Task Definition container_definitions is invalid: Error decoding JSON: invalid character '{' looking for the beginning of object key string`

So in a nutshell, I'm trying to convert:

```
locals {
  env_vars = {
    STAGE = "${var.environment}"
    ENVIRONMENT = "${var.environment}"
    REGION = "${var.region}"
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION = "${var.region}"
  }
}
```

To a string that looks like this:

```
{"name":"STAGE","value":"dev"},
{"name":"ENVIRONMENT","value":"dev"},
{"name":"REGION","value":"us-west-2"},
{"name":"AWS_DEFAULT_REGION","value":"us-west-2"}
```

I'm almost 100% sure the curly braces are throwing me off, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's the `jsonencode` function which could probably help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one too many curly brackets. It should be:

```
container_definitions = templatefile("foo.json", {
    ENVIRONMENT_VARS    = join(",", [for key, value in local.env_vars: 
      "{\"name\":\"${key}\",\"value\":\"${value}}\""
      ])
    })
```

Comment: Dude! How did you figure that out?!  That's insane! I was looking at that for hours and it was just that! THANK YOU SO MUCH!